# Style asp:Checkboxlist in bootstrap panel

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a nice layout for a dynamically loaded checkboxlist but am fairly incompetent when it comes to CSS. I would like the checkboxes to fill the space in the panel body, centre aligned and then start a new row. The repeat columns attribute makes them into a niceish table but they I can't centre align them within the panel body.

HTML

```
<div id="chkBxDiv" runat="server" class="panel panel-danger">
    <div class="panel-heading">Attribute Removal</div>
    <div class="panel-body center-block">
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="checkBoxList" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="4" cssclass="chkboxList"></asp:CheckBoxList>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <asp:Button ID="removeAttrBtn" class="btn btn-danger" runat="server" Text="Remove Selected Attributes" />
    </div>
</div>
```

C#

```
private void populateCheckGrid()
{
    string virusId;
    using (VirusDescriptionActions usersVirus = new VirusDescriptionActions()){
        virusId = usersVirus.GetVirusId();
    }
    List<Virus_Item> currentVirus = getVirus(virusId);
    foreach (Virus_Item V in currentVirus)
    {
        ListItem item = new ListItem();
        item.Text = V.AttributeId.ToString();
        item.Selected = false;
        checkBoxList.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how an asp:CheckBoxList renders in HTML:

```
<table id="MainContent_ctl00">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="MainContent_ctl00_0" name="ctl00$MainContent$ctl00$0" value="text1" type="checkbox">
                <label for="MainContent_ctl00_0">text1</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="MainContent_ctl00_1" name="ctl00$MainContent$ctl00$1" value="text2" type="checkbox">
                <label for="MainContent_ctl00_1">text2</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So style your CSS accordingly for the table elements, inputs, and labels.  Some suggestions: set the table and td width to 100%, set the td text-align to center.  Or to center to whole table, give it a fixed width and set margins left/right to auto.